# Android distribute files with app

Tags: android

When I complete the Android app I am developing I will want to distribute it so that about 300 image files are stored on the sdcard.   Is there any way to do this within the usual automatic installation system?  I don't want to hog the internal memory by including the files in res/raw.

I believe the app can now be built with an instruction to install on the sdcard so I suppose I could do that and include the files in res/raw but is there any limit on the number of files in res/raw?

Comment: What about the `assets` folder?

Comment: If you put them in raw or assets and copy them to the SD card, it will be a waste of space since you will have the pictures in 2 places, and so far as I know, you cannot delete them in the raw or assets folders. And 300*2 images can be quite huge... What about downloading them from Internet on the first run? I've seen that in many apps to download a static database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't want to include the images you could utilize the APK Expansion Files mechanism:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

It will even save it to the sdcard.

Otherwise, you will either have to include the images or download them programmatically to the sdcard.  As for the limits of the res/raw/assets folder I couldn't find any hard figures.  The upper limit though would be the max size of the apk. You could always write a little script that would place 5k/10k/20k 1byte files and see for yourself on that upper bound. If the actual amount of files became an issue you could always zip them in the assets/raw and unzip them to external storage.

I have personally shipped an application for a client that had upwards of 500 images in the assets folder and it worked very well.

Comment: Thanks expansion files looks promising and I hadn't considered the assets folder so I will look at that too,